# Mysql PHP exention unloaded! Error shows in PHP7 How can i solve it?​

Tags: php, mysql, upload, xampp

```
   Mysql PHP exention unloaded! Error shows in PHP7 How can i solve it?​

Version: Windows Server 2012  64-bit
XAMPP Version: 7.0.9
Control Panel Version: 3.2.2
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9NQQ.png

Comment: PHP v7 doesn't ship with the (ancient, long defunct and ages ago deprecated) `mysql` extension.  Your application should use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql extension is deprecated use PDO instead or if you want you can also use MySQLI. That script your trying to install is old prob for php4.

You can use this to have mysql pdo.
php.ini

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Comment: Can you please give a solution how to solve without changing php version. For example some thing adding in php.ini file.

Comment: rewrite the php code to be up to date with the php version